# регулярное выражение для поиска конструкции "присвоение числа переменной" в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

пусть есть строки вида:

- `b = 1`
- `b = [1, 2, 3]`
- `b = {1, 2, 3}`

хочу найти только `b = 1`, то есть любое количество отступов, любой длинны имя, любой длинны число, но только число, вхождения числа в список не подходит.

пробовал:

`(\s*\D*\w+).*=.*?[^[]*(\d+)`

но даже при жадном поиске результат при разбиении на группы, для, например:

`b = [1, 2, 3]` выглядит так: `b` `= [1, 2,` **`3`**, то есть она таки пролезает.

подскажите, как при первом вхождении `[` либо `{` остановить поиск, ибо дальше уже не то.

Comment: Выглядит как перевод с английского ))) О каких отступах идёт речь?

Comment: @Denis640Kb выглядит как вопрос, составленный в 3 ночи. ну например функция в функции в функции в которой `x = 31`, тогда перед `x` стоит 3 таба, или же 12 пробелов..

Comment: Может, `^[_A-Za-z]\w* = \d+$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew оставьте это как ответ.

Comment: @n1tr0xs [Добавил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1076129/182013)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я еще со времен перла помню, что нужно избегать greedy `.*`

```
import re

def findmatch(s):
    try:
        return re.search(r'(\w+\s*?=\s*?\d+)', s).group(1)
    except:
        return None

print(findmatch('b1     =      1'))
print(findmatch('b1=1'))
print(findmatch('b = [1]'))
print(findmatch('1 = [b]'))
print(findmatch('1 = b'))
print(findmatch('lol31331 = 1'))
```

Результат:

```
b1     =      1
b1=1
None
None
None
lol31331 = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте

```
^[_A-Za-z]\w* = \d+$
```

В Python:

```
re.search(r'^[_A-Za-z]\w* = \d+$', text)
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/jZ6198/2). Подробности:

- `^` - начало строки
- `[_A-Za-z]\w*` - знак подчёркивания, а затем 0 и более букв/цифр/_
- `=`  - подстрока  `=`
- `\d+` - 1 и более цифр
- `$` - конец строки.

В можно обойтись без `^` и `$`, если использовать [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch):

```
re.fullmatch(r'[_A-Za-z]\w* = \d+', text)
```

Если хотите разрешить только те цифры, которые соответствуют набору ASCII, передайте в `re.fullmatch` / `re.search` флаг `re.A`/`re.ASCII`:

```
re.fullmatch(r'[_A-Za-z]\w* = \d+', text, re.ASCII)
re.search(r'^[_A-Za-z]\w* = \d+$', text, re.ASCII)
```